# Pandas Read.csv returns arrays as strings

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

So I've been saving data as a .csv using pandas and when I load the .csv back as a df it turns my arrays into strings.

eg:

```
v = np.linspace( 0, 1, 10)
i = []

for j in V:
    itemp = *some calc*
    i = i.append(itemp)
###

df_data = pd.DataFrame({'Vsd_res':[v], 'Isd_res':[i]})
df_res = df_res.append(df_data)
df_res = df_res.reset_index(drop = True)

df_res.to_csv(res.csv)
```

This takes my two arrays and stores them in this format in my .csv:

```
"[-0.5        -0.48989899 -0.47979798 ...]","[-6.835167e-05, -6.683581e-05, -6.678757e-05...]"
```

Here I wonder why the Vsd is stored without commas but Isd is?

And then I load them back in with :

```
df_res = pd.read_csv('res.csv', index_col = 0)
```

What I get looks like:

```
     Vsd_res                                         Isd_res
0   [-0.5     -0.48989899     -0.47979798 ...]    [-6.835167e-05, -6.683581e-05, -6.678757e-05...]
```

what I want:

```
     Vsd_res                               Isd_res
0   [-0.5,-0.48989899,-0.47979798 ...]    [-6.835167e-05, -6.683581e-05, -6.678757e-05...]
```

This kind of picks it up how I want, just the data in each array is a str not a float, this applies to both V and Isd. Matplot cant plot them because a [ is present.

I've tried using eval in the convertors setting but its got an issue with the lack of commas I think.

I'd really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Your code has severe indentation misalignment, please fix it. 2. Add couple of rows in csv to show how it exactly looks like

Comment: csv contains text data. If you're looking to maintain datatypes on save you should use something like `DataFrame.to_pickle` to save and `pandas.read_pickle` to load.

Comment: I've seen it done with .csv and used other peoples data in the past in this format. So I'd rather just stick to it.

Comment: I have question, currently your dataframe has only one row, which contains two arrays, do you want such a dataframe or do you want that each entry of i and the corresponding element of v is in one row? In your example this would be 10 rows

Comment: Ok but should there be arrays inside the rows or single values?

Comment: I want each row to contain those arrays as shown. To clarify, each row should have an array in each column.  (srry my last comment wasnt clear)

Comment: Ok then you have two possibilities either use to_pickle as @HenryEcker said or you can try to use converters when reading data, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524943/how-to-store-2d-array-in-pandas-df-and-read-it-without-it-turning-into-strings/67525664#67525664)

Comment: I see that, and its a good solution.

Comment: Having thought about it, I have a method for this that already works, but the Vsd data has been saved wrong, so it wont work. I have no idea why its been saved that way.

Comment: i found it, list (vsd), sorry for all the bother and thanks for your help.